# rm showing up in SI units

Tags: lyx, siunitx, units

I have written a paper and used the `units` package for all of the units. There is no problem in my computer. But, when I sent it to the publisher (Elsevier) and they tried to compile the file, there is a 'rm' appearing in the middle of units (In the proof version of the manuscript). Here is an example:

```
\SI{160}{\centi\meter\per\s}
```

In my computer, it is shown as below:

[image: I]

But, in the proof version sent to me by the publisher, it is like the following:

[image]

The preamble part is:

```
%% LyX 2.3.5.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[reqno,english,final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\PassOptionsToPackage{version=3}{mhchem}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle= 
{},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={bbbb},
pdfauthor={Seyed Navid Roohani Isfahani}}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{diagbox}
%\usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[range-phrase=--,range-units=single]{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref} %noabbrev
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\journal{bbbb}

\DeclareSIUnit\sccm{sccm}
\DeclareSIUnit\slpm{slpm}

\def\wordcount {1}
\def \Da{{\rm Da}}
\def \Nu{{\rm Nu}}
\def \Rey{{\rm Re}}
\def \Ze{{\rm Ze}}
\def \Le{{\rm Le}}
\def \Pe{{\rm Pe}}
\def \dia{{\mathfrak d}}
\def \dia{D}
\def \e{{\rm e}}

\def \wall{{\rm W}}
\def \reff{{\rm ref}}
\def \ad{{\rm ad}}
\def \av{{\rm avg}}
\def \inn{{\rm in}}
\def \th{{\rm th}}
\def \up{{\rm u}}
\def \dn{{\rm d}}
\def \fl{{\rm F}}
\def \gas{{\rm g}}
\def \lag{\Delta}
\def \step{{\rm s}}
\def \mean{{\rm m}}
\def \nonreactive{{\rm N}}
\def \reactive{{\rm R}}
\def \erf{{\rm erf}}
\def \erfc{{\rm erfc}}

\def \mm{\text -}
\def \pp{+}

\def \m{{\text -1}}
\def \p{{\text 1}}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
\PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\AtBeginDocument{
\def\labelitemi{\normalfont\bfseries{--}}
\def\labelitemii{\(\cdot\)}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\SI{160}{\centi\meter\per\s}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. What is the complete code that you sent of your friend?

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you. Added the preamble part. Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you very much to you :-)...I have compiled your code and it is fine. Peraphs the problem it is of your friend and the reasons can be many...OS, out of data of TeXlive or MikTeX ecc.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive you're both compiling this exact file? It compiles without any problems in all TL versions since 2013, so it's unlikely to be a version problem. More likely is something to do with all the macros defined with `\def`. This is never a good idea, since it will override without warning any existing definition. And the fact that many are  defined using `\rm` makes me suspect that one is missing a \.

Comment: Your edit has changed the question to be about the `units` package, (which I suspect you shouldn't be loading) but the example syntax is definitely from the `siunitx` package, which you are also loading.

Comment: I don’t know what Elsevier does internally, but it’s often the case that publishers include the document you send them as part of a completely different template.  Theirs might erroneously define `\centi`. I note that the old `\rm` command is deprecated in LaTeX, but the most likely cause of this is a typo `rm` for `\rm` somewhere.

Comment: Also, if this is simply an issue with the proofs of the article, just correct the proof, and don't worry about what Elsevier's source document is like. They'll fix what you tell them to fix. (I'm assuming you proof on the PDF not on the LaTeX source.)